# Creating Discount Code System (MySQL/php)

Tags: php, mysql

We have one product, payment is by PayPal. Before going to PayPal need to apply a discount. We want to create a system where people can enter a gift certificate code to get product free (ie 100% discount) or enter some code to get a specific discount (ie SAVE10 - get a 10% discount).

Some codes will be just for one use (ie gift certificates), some can be used multiple times - ie SAVE10. Some will also have expiry dates.

Going to use MySQL and php to put together.

Has anyone out there already done this and put something together? or know of some code we can use to save time? Do not need entire shopping cart just the discount code parts..

Thank you.

Comment: Removed.. Was thining maybe some of the Java guys have a thought.. but yes, decided to remove.. sorry..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is essentially a one class functionality, really. You'd need a class interface that would look like this

```
 class ProductDiscount {
   /**
    * Create a NEW discount code and return the instance of
    *
    * @param $code string      the discount code
    * @param $discount float   price adjustment in % (ex:        
    * @param $options array    (optional) an array of options :
    *                            'expire'   => timestamp    (optional)
    *                            'limited'  => int          (optional)
    * @return ProductDiscount                         
    */
   static public function create($code, $discount, $options = NULL);

   /**
    * This essentially validate the code, and return the instance of the
    * discount if the code exists. The method returns null if the discount 
    * is not valid for any reason. If an instance is returned, to apply
    * the discount, one should invoke the "consume()" method of the instance.
    *
    * @param $code string
    *
    * @return ProductDiscount|null
    */
   static public function validate($code);

   private $_code;     // string
   private $_discount; // float
   private $_expire;   // unix timestamp (see time()) or null if unlimited
   private $_count;    // int or null if unlimited

   private function __construct();
   public function getCode();      // return string
   public function getDiscount();  // return float
   public function isLimited();    // return bool; true if $_count || $_expire is not null
   public function getCount();     // returns int; how many of this discount is left or null if unlimited
   public function getExpireDate();// returns int (unix timestamp) or null if unlimited

   public function consume();      // apply this discount now

   public function consumeAll();   // invalidate this discount for future use
}
```

The DB table could look like this

```
id UNSIGNED INT(10) NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT  -- (Primary Key)
code VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL                   -- (Indexed, unique)
discount UNSIGNED INT(3) NOT NULL           -- percent value 0..100
expire DATETIME DEFAULT NULL                -- unlimited by default
count INT(10) DEFAULT 1                     -- can be NULL
```

---

**Note :** The validation process could just be a simple `SELECT` statement :

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tblproductdiscount
 WHERE code = {$code}                  -- $code = mysql_real_escape_string($code)
   AND (count IS NULL OR count > 0)
   AND (expire IS NULL or expire > NOW())
```

---

Then just use this class when validating checkout form. For example,

```
if (!empty($discountCode)) {
   $discount = ProductDiscount::validate($discountCode);

   if ($discount !== null) {
      $price *= (1 - $discount->getDiscount());
      $discount->consume();
   }
}
```

Well, that's somewhat how I would do it.

Comment: Looks good.. Have you put this into action anywhere where I can see in action?

Comment: never got the contract to do so yet, no. But any other solution would just be overkill. The rest is just mere validation (get data from db, check value, etc.)

Comment: Mmm.. this looks great will try to implement now.. You online for the next hour or so so I can keep you updated?

Comment: Going to have a show/hide box.. Have discount? if they click box for code to appear.. press submit.. db check etc.. if code correct will show the new discount amount with msg discount applied.. else Diiscount Not applied.. Then if all ok, they press button to go to PayPal..

Comment: yes, seems good. You could even perform the discount via Ajax call and return the updated price

Comment: What would be the form in this case?? Say the price is 4.95..??

Comment: well... you perform an Ajax request like `discount.php?code=blah` and the response returns a JSON object, like `{status:0,message:'ok',price:4.95}` or something. The rest depends how your project is structured, I guess

Comment: Also, what happens if they enter the code.. press submit.. code checks.. but then don't go to paypal and pay at this stage.. later come back and enter code.. (and if 1 use only code).. the code will not work?? Do we need some else after paypal use?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3079/discussion-between-yanick-rochon-and-user718359)

Comment: @YanickRochon perfect resource to start with, thanks! Yet I got stuck on some parts and it's been hours... And they closed by question because I asked lots of things (even though they were all connected) and it was too broad.. Lost all my focus by now.

Answer (score 0):

> "Do not need entire shopping cart just the discount code parts.."

This is a really broad question with no specific answer.  Accomplishing what you're talking about requires a lot of integration that would be specific to exactly what you're working on.  If you publish your code to Github or somewhere and are having a specific problem, try re-posting any difficulties you run into.

If you're just looking for some examples of this being done, check out http://www.oscommerce.com/community/contributions,4269 and see if reading the source code gives you some implementation ideas.

Comment: Thanks had a look. But did not want to use the oscommerce shopping cart etc.. Bit overkill.. hope for a quick simple solution..