# coupon code statistics

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have a system that allows users to enter coupons (for example like dell or amazon)

I want to know how much a coupon has been used so after 500 times the coupon is no longer valid.

The way I am thinking right now is to insert the coupon into a table and then `select count(*)` and if it reaches 50 then I don't insert and I return a message saying it's expired.

I think this solution works but I wanted to validate and maybe check if there's a better way to do it.

Comment: without validating with the partner site any system you integrate for counting would be useless.

Comment: Lawrence is right. Unless the coupons are being used on YOUR site then there is no way to count correctly, if at all, without the site that takes the coupons calling your site upon a successful transaction. However, if you had a referral api setup, I would store them as relations in a relational table so I could eliminate duplicate calls, complications or whatever may mess up the data. Plus, you can store any information passed to you so you know more about the user that used the coupon. Standard marketing.

Comment: yes like i said: I have a system ... and the user use the coupon on MY site

Comment: These aren't Dell or Amazon coupons.  The OP just wants a system that works in a similar fashion to handle his or her proprietary coupons.

Comment: You should check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278925/creating-discount-code-system-mysql-php

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I assume you have coupons stored in some table with code, description, etc, etc. add num_used column to it and increment it every time the coupon is used. This way you can still insert the coupon into orders if need be but you don't need to do counts. You simply check how many times it was already used when you load your coupon info. I assume you check validity by coupon code anyway so throw another one in for number of times.

Comment: Sure. For discounts I've implemented in the past I've set up coupons table: id, code, description, type (x% off,$y off, etc), is_limited, limit, num_used, applies_to). You configure your coupon as required. When user enters the code, you perform validation. It can consists of: 1) is the code valid - yes/no 2) does it apply to the product requested - yes/no, 3) is it limited coupon - yes, is the limit reached - yes/no.  You can make it as sophisticated as you want. Once validation passes, you simply increment the counter in the coupon table to keep track of # used.

Comment: @AlexeyGerasimov, may I ask you to have a look at a coupon related question here : http://tinyurl.com/ojokhs5 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can "attach" the coupon code to one order.

Example (for you mysql orders table):
order ABC use coupon "Coupon1"
order BCD use coupon "Coupon1"

And then, yes you can use a function like this one:

```
function getCouponUsage($a_couponCode){
  $res = mysql_query("SELECT couponCode FROM orders WHERE coupon = '$a_couponCode'") or die(mysql_error());
  return mysql_num_rows($res);
}
```

This function will return an integer. Just compare with your limit.

You can also set a hit counter. Let say the coupon can be used 500 times, when someone use the coupon you remove one so the total would be 499 (the coupon can be used 499 from now).