# How to manage discount percentage for discount code system

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on one php product selling site.now over here want to implement Discount System.

When anyone purchase any product, after successful payment am sending one mail with one coupon code with discount amount.

Now I am creating code dynamically using create code combination of random string with time-stamp or whatever and saving that in one table in database with discount amount on that code.

we can create code randomly but how to manage discount amount.

I have read [Creating Discount Code System (MySQL/php)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278925/creating-discount-code-system-mysql-php)

Its for create code but how to manage discount?

we can not create random amount of discount.

Please suggest me how can I specify discount amount for any coupon code.

I want discount amount in percentage.

If any question please comment it, I will update question details asap.

I want any rules for create amount of discount like:

-any user purchasing frequently

-any seasons time

-want to gift or buying in big amount or something

[image]

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I have updated question,still any doubt please comment

Comment: u mean you are creating code you want to associate the discount with it?

Comment: yes Sonali, now problem is how to associate discount on that code,how to specify amount of discount,any logic?

Comment: Do you know the amount of discount you want to apply with a specific code? Is it going to be a percentage value or a currency value, for instance code `newcode` has a discount of 10% or is it that `newcode` has a discount of `$5`, in both cases above it should be a question of business rules, to save the value, create another field in your sql for it, let me know if I am on the right track here?

Comment: posted my answer..but take into account whether you want percentage based or value based discount and as sated by @Armand the currency also..i worked on such system...so answer is relevant to that..Hope it helps

Comment: @Armand no I am not sure hot to create discount amount.is there any logic like any user purchasing for more then 5 time then give them more discount or like any logic(any rules for create discount amount).

Comment: you need to set your own rules there are many possibilities

Comment: @Sonali so I want that possibilities. how to manage it,Please help me.

Comment: Discount code - One time use or multiple time use?

Comment: @Sonali Just one time

Comment: ok then this is schema is fine...will update the answer as and when u require..:)

Comment: It's your business (or your client's)! What's your *business rule* about discounts? If you have none, think about it. If you have *"discount code, ???, discount!"*, you need to fill in the blank first.

Comment: @deceze I have no idea of any rules that's why I am asking it.And how to apply that rules.

Comment: **What's your _business case_?!** How much discount do you want to give your customers? How often? Is it a percentage? Is it a fixed amount? This is not a technical question, it's a question of how you want to operate your store from a financial and marketing perspective!

Comment: @deceze so where I can ask this question?I want some theoretical concept

Comment: I don't know. http://answers.onstartups.com perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

**N.B.** - This is a rough idea.

You can create a form wherein you allow the user to enter discount percentage (not greater than 100 or according to your requirements. Taking into consideration you want to use discounts in percentage on the Total amount of purchases). Then associate a randomly generated code to this discount. Also you can associated a status with the code such as used or unsused to know whether the discount code has been user by customers or not.

Database schema would be like follows for discount and code

```
  CREATE TABLE  `mydatabase`.`discounts` (
     `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
      `discount` FLOAT( 3, 2 ) NOT NULL ,
      `code` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
      `status` BOOLEAN NOT NULL ,
      `emailed` BOOLEAN NOT NULL ,
       );

   status would be 0 for unused codes and 1 for used codes
   emailed would be 0 for not emailed codes and 1 for emailed codes
```

Default values for status and emailed will be 0

Answers to your rules

I want any rules for create amount of discount like:

-any user purchasing frequently- create a list of users who have purchased frequently (like for more than 5)

-any seasons time- don't set expiry for discount code but dont use discount coupons which are used once (to keep it simple)

-want to gift or buy in big amounts or something- users will be given the coupon codes priorly so they can redeem them while placing the orders.

Comment: your means create code and stored in database and after payment mail random code from database to user?

Comment: no, you can list this on a page and have another flag wherein you can email it. Your problem is same as a project i worked upon where i also had an option to email the discount :)

Comment: Thanks @Sonali for answer but my problem is how to create discount amount? is there any logic like any user purchasing for more then 5 time then give them more discount or like any logic(any rules for create discount amount).

Comment: set your own rules or you can just email the users the discount. discount amount is created as I said now it depends on you to which user you have to assign or email the discount. You can have a users list wherein you list the users who have more than 5 processed orders in your store...

Comment: Coupon codes may be configured with a start or ending date, number of times they may be used, and an minimum order value.

Comment: Thanks sonali for your effort

Comment: happy to have helped..:)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36087/discussion-between-anytime-and-sonali)