# Save Inputs into database & class errors - building coupon system

Tags: php, mysql

Okay, I'm building (trying) a coupon code system for my admin panel, what I want to achieve is allow admin to manually create coupons by setting its **coupon_code** and **coupon_discount (1% TO 100%)**. When he will submit, it will be stored in two different tables of two dbs.

TABLE **coupons:**

- coupon_id INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT - Primary key
- coupon_code VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL - unique
- discount DECIMAL(3,2)
- expire DATETIME  -NULL
- count  INT(10)  -NULL

**I checked lots of examples on the net and this is my probably poorly written class:**

```
class ProductDiscount {

static public function validate($coupon_code);

private $_coupon_code;     // string
private $_coupon_discount; // integer??
private $_expire;   // null cause unlimited
private $_count;    // null

private function __construct();    //for this line I got an error
public function getCouponCode();      // return string
public function getCouponDiscount();  // return 
public function getCount();     // returns null unlimited
public function getExpireDate();// null

public function useDiscount();      // apply this discount now

public function useAllDiscount();   // invalidate this discount for future use
```

**COUPONS.PHP - new coupon creation**

On the admin side, I am totally lost about how to pass the coupon_code and coupon_discount to the database...How to utilize the functions that I wrote in the class...This is what I did:

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
$coupon_code = $_POST['coupon_code'];
$coupon_discount = $_POST['coupon_discount'];

//insert into db for admin
$connect = new mysqli("localhost","-----","-------","--------");
$stmt = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO `coupons` (`coupon_code`, `coupon_discount`) VALUES (?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param('si', $coupon_code, $coupon_discount);
$stmt->execute();
$connect->close();
}  
?>
```

**I'm getting undefined index errors for both the coupon_code and coupon_discount..**

If I require_once my class file here, I'm getting **Non-abstract method ProductDiscount::create() must contain body error.**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="createcoupon.php">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Coupon Code</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="coupon_code" id="couponCode" placeholder="e.g SAVE10">
    </div>
    </div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Coupon Discount</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="coupon_discount" id="couponDiscount" placeholder="e.g 10 for 10%">
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-3">
  <input type="submit" style="background-color:#7575DD; padding:0 !important; color:white;" name="create_coupon" value="Create Coupon" class="btn btn-default"/>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

**Here is my createcoupon.php**:

```
<?php
//Connect to the 1st db
    $coupon_code = $_POST['coupon-code'];
    $coupon_discount = $_POST['coupon-discount'];
//the prepared stmt to insert into db1

//Connect to the 2nd tb
    $coupon_code = $_POST['coupon-code'];
    $coupon_discount = $_POST['coupon-discount'];
//prepared stmt to insert into db2
header("location: http://example.com/admin/coupons");
?>
```

It's 4am and been hours that I'm trying to learn these.

So *my question is:* **"How can I save the necessary form data to the table in the correct way and save the coupon into the table?"**

(**edited and specified my current problem only, can you reopen?**)

(**commented the long/unnecessary parts to clarify**)

Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: Sidenote: Don't use hyphens for variables `$coupon-code`, use underscores `$coupon_code`, otherwise it will error out.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks! I edited my question to be more precise. Asking all at once was a bad idea...

Comment: You're welcome Ekin. In regards to *"how do I check if there is a coupon with the same code"*, one method is to use `mysqli_num_rows()`, however you probably won't need to worry about that since you've set two of your columns as UNIQUE, but that's a method you can use if you really wish to check if it exists.

Comment: `discount ???` - that could be an `int` or `decimal` or `double` depending on how you wish to query later on as far as percentages go, but you can use PHP to do calculations afterwards. `count ??? default NULL (unlimited)` you can use an `int` for that if that's for a counter of sorts.

Comment: Okay @Fred-ii- all understood sir! About calculating the final `$amount`, I have the `$unitCost = 6995;` in this way, then it directly goes to Stripe after the shipping rates. So I need to do something like: e.g for a 10% discount code : `$discountedAmount = $amount - $amount * 0.10` but in that case how do I store the coupon_discount as a float on the database?

Comment: or is there a better way to do that?

Comment: SQL has `float` as a column type.

Comment: oh...never used and don't even remember that, okay thanks for all the info :)

Comment: You're welcome Ekin.

Comment: Sorry to bother again @Fred-ii-, but here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278925/creating-discount-code-system-mysql-php he answered saying: discount UNSIGNED INT(3) NOT NULL. What suits exactly for that?

Comment: TBH Ekin, I don't know what the `UNSIGNED` is. Many things about SQL I am not yet aware of. I suggest you Google it. You will find something I'm sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so far, I managed to solve it. Using bootstrap table.

With an "add coupon" button:

```
<button data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' type='button' class='btn btn-primary' style="margin: 20px;" name='add-btn' id='add-btn'>Add Coupon</button>
```

1. `data-toggle='modal'` and `data-target='#myModal'` to link the modal div to the button
2. SELECT statement to get the coupon table and pull the data into a bootstrap table.

   ```
   <div style="padding: 20px;">
   <?php
   $con = new mysqli("------","--------","--------","-----");
   $query = "SELECT * FROM coupons WHERE expire > NOW() OR expire IS NULL OR expire = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'";
   if ($result = $con->query($query))
   {

   echo "<table border='1' class='table table-hover' data-toggle='table'>
   <tr>
   <th>Coupon Code</th>
   <th>Amount</th>
   <th>Expiry</th>
   <th></th>
   </tr>";

   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['coupon_code'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['coupon_discount'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['expire'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td><button data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' type='button' class='btn btn-primary' name='submit-btn' data-id='" . $row["coupon_id"] ."'>Edit</button></td>";
   echo "</tr>";
   }
   echo "</table>";
   }
   mysqli_close($con);
   ?>
   ```

These are the modal divs and form to post the inputs and save it to the table.

```
    <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Coupon Information</h4>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
<form action='createcoupon.php' method='POST'>
<input type='hidden' name='coupon_id' id='couponId' value='0'/>
<input type="text" class="form-control" style="margin-bottom:10px;" name="coupon_code" id="couponCode" placeholder="e.g SAVE10">
<input type="number" class="form-control" style="margin-bottom:10px;" name="coupon_discount" id="couponDiscount" placeholder="e.g 10 for 10%">
<input type="text" class="form-control" style="margin-bottom:10px;" name="coupon_expire" id="couponExpire" placeholder="e.g 01/01/2015">
<input class="btn btn-primary" type='submit' name='submit-btn' value='Save' />
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

This is the javascript

```
<script>
// Function added to each edit button. Sets the ID to the button "data-id" value.
// Finds the parent (td) of the button, then goes to each sibling with the correct class name
// and changes the modal input value to the inner text of the TD
var editfunction = function() {
    $('#couponId').val($(this).attr('data-id'));
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    $('#couponCode').val($(parent).siblings('.coupon_code').text());
    $('#couponDiscount').val($(parent).siblings('.coupon_discount').text());
    $('#couponExpire').val($(parent).siblings('.coupon_expire').text());
};

// Called on the ADD button only
// Sets the ID to 0 (to INSERT the record on the form submit)
// Sets the other inputs to blank values
function addNewCoupon()
{
    $('#couponId').val('0');
    $('#couponCode').val('');
    $('#couponDiscount').val('');
    $('#couponExpire').val('');
}

// When the page has loaded...
// Attach the edit function call to the click event of each edit button
// Attach the add new coupon to the click event of the add button
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button[name="submit-btn"]').click(editfunction);
    $('#add-btn').click(function() { addNewCoupon(); });
});
</script>
```

Then on the createcoupon.php I did this:

```
// Check connection
$coupon_id = intval($_POST['coupon_id']);
$coupon_code = $_POST['coupon_code'];
$coupon_discount = $_POST['coupon_discount'];
```

and after with mysqli connection I inserted/updated (in an if else statement, "if is 'add coupon' or 'edit coupon') them.

I solved this in the end, If you have any ideas about it, please share with me so that I can improve.

I hope these codes can be useful for someone!

Thanks for your time.